# How to use Callback on Moq's SetUpSequence?

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I'm using Moq version 4.8 and have a method to mock and assert its parameter. I started with this mocked method:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.Update(It.IsAny<MyClass>))
    .Callback((MyClass c) =>
    {
        // some assertions
    })
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(updatedClass));
```

where I update an object of type `MyClass` and do a number of assertions on that object. This works just fine.

I've just added logic to the method calling `Update` to retry calling it if exceptions are thrown. So I want to implement a new unit test that throws exceptions a few times and then returns and be able to do the assertions like before. So I tried `SetupSequence` as follows:

```
mock.SetupSequence(m => m.Update(It.IsAny<MyClass>))
    .Throws(new Exception("test exception 1"))
    .Throws(new Exception("test exception 2"))
    .Callback((MyClass c) =>
    {
        // some assertions
    })
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(updatedClass));
```

But `ISetupSequence` doesn't support `Callback`. Is there a way to mock `Throws` and `Returns` calls in order while keeping a pre call `Callback` to `Returns`?

Comment: You may look at [#573](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/573) issue in Moq repository. As well as at [Moq sequential callbacks](https://darchuk.net/2018/02/02/moq-sequential-callbacks/). Not sure that it's more elegant, since it's quite opinion-based

Comment: Thanks for the links, they were helpful. Also reworded the question to make it less opinion based. My work around feels like a hack to me, that's why I'm looking for a better way of doing this.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54342383/moq-sequence-with-callback-c-sharp)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the time being I've been doing the this as a work around:

```cs
int callCount = 0;
mock.Setup(m => m.Update(It.IsAny<MyClass>))
    .Callback((MyClass c) =>
    {
        callCount++;
        if (callCount <=2)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Test Exception #{callCount}");
        }
        else
        {
            callCount = 0; // this is needed if you're gonna use callCount for multiple setups
            // some assertions
        }
    })
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(updatedClass));
```

Feels like a hack, but does what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [MockSequence](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#miscellaneous), so that you can add Callback after `.Setup()`.

> ```
> var mock = new Mock<IFoo>(MockBehavior.Strict);
> var sequence = new MockSequence();
>
> _fooService.InSequence(sequence).Setup(x => x.FooMethod(a)).ReturnsAsync(b);
> _barService.InSequence(sequence).Setup(x => x.BarMethod(c)).ReturnsAsync(d);
> _bazService.InSequence(sequence).Setup(x => x.BazMethod(e)).ReturnsAsync(f);
> ```

Comment: While you can call `.Setup` on an `InSequence`, you can't call `.Throw` or `.Callback` which are what I'm looking for.

Comment: @alamoot - Callback only works after a setup. This is the solution and works perfectly for me :-)

Comment: MockSequence seems to check that the calls are coming in order, while SetupSequence() delivers return values in order (each for every call of the same method).

Answer (score 6):

I have used this approach to capture each instance of a request to a method and also return a sequence of values.

```
var requests = new List<SomeRequest>();
var sequence = new MockSequence();
foreach (var response in responses)
{
    someMock.InSequence(sequence)
        .Setup(x => x.SomeMethod(It.IsAny<SomeRequest>()))
        .Callback<SomeRequest>(r => requests.Add(r))
        .ReturnsAsync(response);
}
```

Given some list of pre-defined responses, the above will capture all the requests made to a mocked method and return the sequence of responses.